# why there is no AND operator in regular expression?

Tags: python, python-re

there is an OR operator | in regular expression (re module), but why there is no AND operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can't have one section of a string be both 'abc' and 'def'.  It is either one or the other.

Comment: It can be both `.*abc.*` and `.*def.*`

Comment: `abcdef` matches both.